# operator + cannot be applied to java.lang.charsequence

Tags: button, operators, charsequence

Trying to make a calculator, here's the button method when the line with the * is ran it comes up with the error "operator + cannot be applied to java.lang.charsequence". If any one know's a way around this please help.

```
    public void Button_Click(View view) {
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    Button b = (Button)view;
    if ((result.getText() == "0")||(operation_pressed))
        result.setText("");
    operation_pressed = false;

    if (b.getText() == ".") {
        result.getText() = result.getText() + b.getText()); ***
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert a charsequence to a String apply .toString() to the CharSequence Object and you should be fine to use + operators:

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html][1]

Also it looks like you have a syntax error:

> ```
>    result.getText() = result.getText() + b.getText()); *** the last ) is too much
> ```

Furthermore you cannot write into getText() .. Getters (indicated by getXXX()) should be used to get values while Setters (indicated by setXXX()) should be used to store values into an object.

> result.setText(result.getText().toString() + b.getText().toString())

Comment: thanks, you sort of helped but now I get the error 

    operator + cannot be applied to 'void java.lang.string

    this has left me as confused as ever with my problem. any more help would be great, thanks.

Comment: never mind I just declared a string that was result_text then instead of declaring result's text as a variable I used result.setText

result.setText(result_text + b.getText().toString());

Comment: glad the advice could help you! Nevertheless I'm wondering why you had the problem. since both toString Methods should return a string!

Comment: Thanks and I have no idea why that happened... I am using Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.9 so maybe that was the problem, anyway thanks.